# Differentiate invoke-WebRequest status codes

Tags: powershell, http-status-codes, invoke-webrequest

I am attempting to validate URLs prior to downloading those files, and I want to differentiate between things like a path that requires credentials vs a bad path.

I have this at the moment

```
function Get-UrlStatusCode([string] $Url) {
    try {
        return (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url -UseBasicParsing -DisableKeepAlive -Method:head).StatusCode
    } catch [Net.WebException] {
        return "$([Int]$_.Exception.Response.StatusCode) $($_.Exception.Response.statusDescription)"
    }
}

(Get-UrlStatusCode 'http://AWSBUCKETPATH/Test_Public.xml')
(Get-UrlStatusCode 'http://AWSBUCKETPATH/Test_Private.xml')
(Get-UrlStatusCode 'http://AWSBUCKETPATH/Test_Missing.xml')
```

For the public path I am getting the expected StatusCode of 200, but both the private and the missing examples are returning 403 Forbidden. Is this a failure in my code, or something that needs to be configured at AWS to provide a 404 Not Found for the bad path, or is this just not something that is possible despite the existence of 404 as a code?

Comment: This will be something that needs to be configured in AWS since you have permission to access all pages given the correct credentials etc. You can always spoof that 404 in your code if you treat 403 and 404 the same? but lets pretend I never suggested that

Comment: Shouldn't that be `-Method 'Head'` ?

Comment: @Theo all `-Method 'Head'`, `-Method Head` and `-Method:Head` are valid and equivalent…

Comment: @JosefZ Thanks, didn't know that. I have only used the `-Param:$something` syntax on swithes, not enum values..

Comment: @Theo The quotes are optional (because there's no spaces in the string?), and you can also use the `:` between argument and value, which I did when I first started with PS to make the relationship more clear. I haven't gotten out of the habit in my own code, though I usually do change stuff here since it's not "normal". I use K&R "One true brace" too, but that doesn't cause as much confusion as the `:` does. :-)

Comment: Ah, interesting. Not the lack of spaces, it only works with enums. Makes sense.

Comment: @otter, any suggestions on how to configure that in AWS? My Google-Fu is failing me.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I am sorry! Maybe ask another question under the appropriate ```aws``` tag